# Can a generic function be used for summing structs?

Tags: c++, generics, generic-programming

Suppose I have a struct, such as:

```
struct Foo {
    double a;
    float b;
    int c;
};
```

Summing `fooA` and `fooB` (both of type `Foo`) would equate to:

```
{fooA.a + fooB.a, 
 fooA.b + fooB.b, 
 fooA.c + fooB.c};
```

Now my question is, could a generic function be created that would sum structs together in this manner? i.e.:

```
template <typename StructType>
StructType sumStructs(StructType A, StructType B) {
    // sum component with one another, return resulting struct
}
```

Alternatively, what limitations would you need to impose for it to be possible?

Comment: No, C++ doesn't have [introspection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_introspection) so there is no way to get structure members of unknown structures.

Comment: I think you don't need introspection, compile-time reflection is what's needed here. And that can be achieved by various means, but not with "vanilla" C++. (like multi-stage builds with code generation).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Joachim Pileborg put it,

> No, C++ doesn't have [introspection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_introspection) so there is no way to get structure
>   members of unknown structures.

So what I ended up doing was overloading `+` for each struct individually. This in turn allowed me to create a generic function that takes a node, and sums all of its parent structs (useful, for example, for summing positions, to get the absolute position of an object).

Answer (score -1):

Yes you certainly can.  You can also overload the + operator and would get this type of genericism for free.  There are many ideas in c++ that are like this. `Less<T>` or `begin` and `end` free functions.

Comment: How is the OP supposed to get all fields of the structs inside the template function/method, with the exact struct type being unknown?

Comment: you can duck type a set of stucts or provide an adaptor template class or overload the operator. Less is an example of a template adaptor..

Comment: Like, duck type every possible set of every possible field type?

Comment: In general the adaptor is for non conforming types.  Similar to less.  If you have a < operator then that is what less uses if not you can specialize less.